# Where Xenakis used intersection?

Tags: composition

I understood intersection in Xenakis sieve theory, as he explained himself [here](https://monoskop.org/images/7/74/Xenakis_Iannis_Formalized_Music_Thought_and_Mathematics_in_Composition.pdf). But can anyone provide me a musical example from its production where he effectively used this?

Comment: You might need to seek out someone who is very familiar with Xenakis's music. I looked through the pdf you linked and it's quite heady stuff and very specific to Xenakis himself (since he wrote it). Because of the difficulty and specificity, you'd more than likely need to find a scholar who really specializes in that music.

Answer (score 0):

Although I can't trace a thread between sieve theory and Xenakis's own compositions, a generalization of it (weighted sieves: set-theoretic operations defined as in [fuzzy set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_set#Fuzzy_logic)) is used effectively by Sever Tipei's 1980's compositions using his (Sever's) MP1 software.  An accessible composition and an accessible description(!) is [Maiden Voyages](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3680319).